# Appending to javascript modal though loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending content to a modal using javascript. I am appending different data to different table rows and table cells.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

I want my data, for example, name, to go in column 1, id to go in column 2 etc etc. Then make a new tr when the first set of looping is complete.

I am looping like below, but this does not seem to be working

```
for (row = 0; row < $(this).data("name").length; row++) {
    $("#myModal").find(".table").append("<tr><td>" + $(this).data("name")[row] + "</td>");

    for (row = 0; row < $(this).data("id").length; row++) {
        $("#myModal").find(".table").append("<tr><td>" + $(this).data("id")[row] + "</td>");

        for (row = 0; row < $(this).data("fruit").length; row++) {
            $("#myModal").find(".table").append("<tr><td>" + $(this).data("fruit")[row] + "</td>");

            for (row = 0; row < $(this).data("state").length; row++) {
                $("#myModal").find(".table").append("<tr><td>" + $(this).data("state")[row] + "</td></tr></tbody></table>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also My data elements are different arrays and have different lengths.

Comment: Just a suggestion - for readability, maybe consider creating a variable to store the `#myModal` jQuery object in, so you don't have to keep repeating `$("#myModal").find(".table")` - for instance, `var myModalTable = $("#myModal").find(".table");`.

Comment: @alex not to mention performance...

Comment: What is $(this).data("name") ?

Comment: $(this).data is how its reading the data that has been passed. My issue is not data being passed. If i have one for loop this works perfectly. Its when i add more than one for loop it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess it doesn't work because everything is incorrect here. Sorry but...

Firstly, you work with jQuery like it builds a string of HTML. Probably copying server-side code here? jQuery (and JS to some point) doesn't work with strings, it works with DOM elements. So you don't add `<tr><td>` in beginning, put some your content and then do `'. You do it like this:

```
var row = $('<tr></tr>');
var elem = $('<td></td>');
elem.html('someText');
row.append(elem);
```

or just:

```
$('<tr></tr>').append('<td>someText</td>');
```

It already creates a TableRow element inside the jQuery container, you can check it with `console.log(row[0])`, it's not just the beginning of a HTML string, it's the JS object in full rights that can be attached to other DOM elements on the page, and other elements can be added into it by calling its methods.

Secondly, even if it would work like this, with strings, you put a cycle into a cycle inside a cycle working inside another cycle and... Just imagine how much times it'd add `</td></tr></tbody></table>` into your page. Something is definitely not right here.

And thirdly, you use one variable (`window.row` cause any variable created without `var` or `let` keywords is a `window` property) as a counter for every of these nested cycles. They overwrite it in their own logic and turn everything into a mess that will stuck in an endless cycle or will work just once or... Whatever can happen!

So maybe I don't understand something but your code doesn't work because it simply can't work no matter what.

Comment: As i stated before it works if i put only one for loop. And it works because this is wrapped in a php function which returns a variable. that variable is constantly being appended and displayed on the page, that is why my quotes seem to be untraditional. But as i stated before if i just keep one for loop it works just fine.

Comment: The issue is multiple looping.

Comment: Yeah, but this is not PHP, it's a JS code using jQuery and this code can't work because JS works with HTML totally different from PHP.

Comment: This works i dont know where you are not following. The code i have above is the same as me putting $("#example").html($(this).data("example")); And that works

Comment: It works because a browser (and jQuery) fixes your code by repairing orphan tags (like `<table>`) and ignoring excessive tags (like `</table>` in the end of your superloop). I already explained why your looping doesn't work - it uses one variable for every loop.

Comment: Only when i have one for loop it works, thus one for loop does not mean its a superloop. How will i change the context of my code to work for multiple loops?

Comment: Firstly you must use different variables for different loops. Either `var i, j, k, l` or `let row` (the `let` will let you use one name for each counter as every `row` will be visible only inside the block it's created and not override the `row` one level up).